# Syntax to concatenate 2 select count statements in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 COUNT queries against the same table that are a sub query in another select query.
What I want to do is something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Stuff ,
    ((SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) from cTable WHERE Water = 'wet')) AS VARCHAR) +'/'+
    ((SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) from cTable WHERE sky = 'blue')) AS VARCHAR) AS StockCount
FROM  aTable 
WHERE MyData = 'Rocks'
```

and output something like 4/5 for each Stuff in aTable.

My difficulty is the syntax of the nesting required.

First I have 2 integers that should be cast as string from int, then I have the concatenation, then to make things even simpler, the AS keyword has to be outside the combined query when it is a subselect, and the Sub-Selects have to be in parenthesis. After re-writing this statement 10 times, I'm at my wits end

Here are my 2 queries.

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    Process_PartsIssued 
WHERE 
    (Process_PartsIssued.OEMPartCode = Part_Catalog.ID  
     AND TechStockFlag = 'True' 
     AND PartReturned = 'False' 
     AND UsedByUser IS NULL)

SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    Process_PartsIssued 
WHERE 
    (Process_PartsIssued.OEMPartCode = Part_Catalog.ID 
     AND PartReturned = 'False' 
     AND UsedByUser IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *always* using a length with `varchar()`.

Second, you can do this with a single query, using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Stuff,
       (select (cast(sum(case when water = 'wet' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar(255)) + '/' +
                cast(sum(case when sky = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar(255))
               ) as StockCount
FROM  aTable 
WHERE MyData = 'Rocks';
```

EDIT:

For your particular queries:

```
SELECT stuff,
       (SELECT cast(sum(case when TechStockFlag = 'True' AND PartReturned = 'False' AND  UsedByUser IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) as varchar(255)) + '/' +
               cast(sum(case when PartReturned = 'False' AND  UsedByUser IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) as varchar(255))
        FROM Process_PartsIssue
        WHERE Process_PartsIssued.OEMPartCode = Part_Catalog.ID
       ) as StockCount
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three separate questions:

1) How do I aggregate rows based on criteria I'm not filtering by or grouping by?

```
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TechStockFlag = 'True' THEN 1 END)
```

2) How do I convert a number to a string for string concatenation?

```
    LTRIM(STR(number))
```

3) How do I reference something from outside a subquery?

```
    SELECT
      x,
      (SELECT .... FROM TableB WHERE ... = A.y)
    FROM TableA A
```

or

```
    SELECT
      A.x,
      B.y
    FROM TableA A
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT .... FROM TableB WHERE ... = A.y) B
```

Putting it together:

```
SELECT Stuff, Partcount
FROM Part_Catalog
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    LTRIM(STR(COUNT(CASE WHEN TechStockFlag = 'True' THEN 1 END)))
    + '/'
    + LTRIM(STR(COUNT(*))) PartCount
  FROM Process_PartsIssued
  WHERE Process_PartsIssued.OEMPartCode = Part_Catalog.ID
    AND PartReturned = 'False'
    AND UsedByUser IS NULL
) B
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your 2 queries you could create something as the following:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN TechStockFlag = 'True' AND PartReturned = 'False' AND  UsedByUser IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NVARCHAR(5)) + '/' +
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN PartReturned = 'False' AND  UsedByUser IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NVARCHAR(5)) AS 'StockCount'
FROM Process_PartsIssued
INNER JOIN Part_Catalog
    ON Process_PartsIssued.OEMPartCode = Part_Catalog.ID
```